# Как убрать границу между виджетами с помощью Qt Style Sheets

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Пишу редактор текста на Qt 5.5. Когда начал заниматься дизайном, решил использовать qss и столкнулся с проблемой. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы фон редактора и фон панели статуса сливались а-ля Sublime Text 3, и получалось единое целое. Ну, я установил одинаковый цвет фона, и вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй у statusBar'a свойство `frameShape` уставновить в `NoFrame`, `lineWidth` = 0

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скриншоту, надо выставить `border: 0px;` для основного виджета с текстом, а также для `QLabel` в статус баре, где "Line 1, Column 0". Так как у статусбара вроде рамки нет.